# Is there a way to extract the compiled Lua code (.lc file) from the LFS (Lua Flash Store) image?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I've had my laptop stolen from me a day after writing a very large and boring piece of Lua code. I did not commit this code to git, so I no longer have the .lua files :( However I still do have the debug esp8266 module where this code has been uploaded after compiling it into [Lua File Store (LFS)](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/lfs/) image with **luac.cross** from nodemcu-firmware.

I was able to extract the LFS image from esp8266 back to my PC. Now I'd love to give  [luadec](https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec) a try to decompile that code, but to do so I need to extract the compiled Lua files (.lc) from that LFS image. Is there any reasonable way to do so?

Comment: Interesting problem - sorry you have to go through this. This is so highly specific that I suggest you tag @TerryE on https://gitter.im/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.

Comment: @MarcelStör Thanks, done that. Terry's reply was "Not realistically practical", hence it seems I'll just have to rewrite that lost piece of code from scratch.